# How to fade in element containing class 'hide' in Foundation 6?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, zurb-foundation

I have a div with class 'hide' as below:

```
<div class="form-group hide field-contactform-phone_no">
```

I've googled this and looked at jQuery docs (fadeIn) but wondering what is the best way of achieving fadeIn effect on this element (which uses Foundation 6's visibility class of 'hide').

I'm thinking one way is to call following procedures:

```
$('.field-contactform-phone_no').hide()
$('.field-contactform-phone_no').removeClass('hide')
$('.field-contactform-phone_no').fadeIn(1000);
```

This does seem to work but is not a very elegant way of doing it. Any better ways?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can chain methods in jQuery. Doing so is actually often quite necessary when working with website effects.

```
$('.field-contactform-phone_no').hide().removeClass('hide').fadeIn(1000);
```

Comment: Cool that will do then :)